# Is it possible to pick a specific button, that is on a page multiple times with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to code a program for somebody, that is possible to send and delete messages at the same time in the browser Discord application.(I think he wants to use this to spam?) He told me to write the code in Python, so I used python with Selenium. At this point I got everything working so far, the login works, the channel select works if you just insert the channel link directly. It also managed to let it send some messages. But problem now is, that I don't know how to delete the message after it was send, beacuse you need to click a "More" button first. But  this more Button

Answer (score 0):

I would use Webbot for that:

from webbot import Browser

web = Browser()

web.click('More')

that module has quite a few useful simple functions so i encourage you to try it